# Jsoup html parsing LOC

Tags: jsoup

Hi I am new to Jsoup and I couldn't find how to count the lines of code in an HTML webpage for a html metric project I am working on.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why does youtube have 9379 lines? When I view source in chrome I see at least 10k

Comment: Every time its different depending on the page and different browsers but I just wanted to be sure people knew what I meant by loc in a website, removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: George, I don't think you need Jsoup to find out how many lines of code an HTML file is composed of. In fact I don't even think Jsoup would help you because it just converts the HTML to a Document and drops all reference to the source. Can you not just count the number of line breaks?

Comment: It really depends on what you consider to be "lines of code". I could say put everything on a single line, or I could insert line breaks here and there. I could even insert arbitrary line breaks at my own discretion whenever I feel like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this might help. But it all depends on how the page is created. Some times it may not be formatted, sometimes it may be obfuscated and may result improper count.
However jsoup give a level of formatting. So this should help.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class LineCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get();

            int noOfLines = doc.html().split("\n").length;
            System.out.println(noOfLines);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess this is as close as it gets to counting loc I also didn't find any other solution. It's not that accurate but it will have to do. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the number of lines exactly as in the original html, you can turn the prettyPrint setting off. The below code will print the number of lines in the html code.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
System.out.println(doc.toString().split("\n").length);
```

If you set prettyPrint True, jSoup will format the html code properly and it will insert newline characters so that end div tags are in a new line, etc. So, the lines of code will increase.